# Daily digest emails on user registration

Tags: php, email, notifications, registration

I'm writing a simple signup page for a small-scale text message service - sort of like a mailing list, but instead of emails, I send text messages to those who sign up with me.

Since its small-scale and I don't want it to get too complicated my current idea is to add users to a mySQL database and then manually add the *new* users to the texting list (which is managed separate unfortunately).

I was wondering if there's a way to generate a daily email digest of new registrations, so that it would just email me all the new registrations that happened today instead of an email every time someone signs up. Is this possible? Perhaps a CRONTAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Store the signup date in your table. Write a script which retrieves the list of people that signed up today and set up crontab to run that script at 11:59PM each night.

```
SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE signup_date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: CURDATE() skips mysql query cache! But then again that does not matter when you only execute query 1 time :P